# Sybase ASE: Get list of REAL PK and FK via query

Tags: sql, primary-key, sap-ase

I have some Sybase ASE tables with primary and foreign keys and I want to get list of REAL PK and FK for these tables. And this information should be returned via SELECT query to system tables.
All queries which uses queries to 'syskeys' are not correct since syskeys contains only logical references for tables which is created via sp_foreignkey. 
For example I have below tables:

```
create table tbl_pk1
(col1 int primary key,
col2 int);

create table tbl_pk3
(col1 int null,
col2 int);

sp_primarykey  'tbl_pk3', 'col1'
```

And below query will return only 'tbl_pk3'.

```
select t.name  from syskeys i INNER JOIN sysobjects t ON i.id = t.id where  t.name in ('tbl_pk1', 'tbl_pk3')
```

I know what 'sp_helpconstraint' procedure can help me, but I can't call it in SELECT.
Maybe someone can help me with query to system tables to get actual information about primary and foreign keys for tables?

Comment: You may want to update your question with some examples of the desired output (eg, constraint name? table name of the pk? table names of the fk? names of columns in the pk/fk?); I'd also recommend you take a look at the source code for sp_helpconstraint (`exec sybsystemprocs..sp_helptext sp_helpconstraint null,null,showsql`) ... you should be able to use this code to create your own SELECT to display the constraint data in the format you desire

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are how it can be done

```
select user_name(o.uid) user_name, object_name(i.id) table_name, index_col(object_name(i.id), i.indid, 1) column_name, 1 column_id, i.name as con_name 
    from sysindexes i, sysobjects o where object_name(i.id) = 'tbl_pk_mult' and user_name(o.uid) = 'dbo' and  status & 2048 = 2048 and i.id = o.id and index_col(object_name(i.id), i.indid, 1) is not null         union         
select user_name(o.uid) user_name, object_name(i.id) table_name, index_col(object_name(i.id), i.indid, 2) column_name, 2 column_id, i.name as con_name 
    from sysindexes i, sysobjects o where object_name(i.id) = 'tbl_pk_mult' and user_name(o.uid) = 'dbo'  and  status & 2048 = 2048 and i.id = o.id and index_col(object_name(i.id), i.indid, 2) is not null         union         
select user_name(o.uid) user_name, object_name(i.id) table_name, index_col(object_name(i.id), i.indid, 3) column_name, 3 column_id, i.name as con_name 
    from sysindexes i, sysobjects o where object_name(i.id) = 'tbl_pk_mult' and user_name(o.uid) = 'dbo'  and  status & 2048 = 2048 and i.id = o.id and index_col(object_name(i.id), i.indid, 3) is not null         union         
select user_name(o.uid) user_name, object_name(i.id) table_name, index_col(object_name(i.id), i.indid, 4) column_name, 4 column_id, i.name as con_name 
    from sysindexes i, sysobjects o where object_name(i.id) = 'tbl_pk_mult' and user_name(o.uid) = 'dbo'  and  status & 2048 = 2048 and i.id = o.id and index_col(object_name(i.id), i.indid, 4) is not null         union         
select user_name(o.uid) user_name, object_name(i.id) table_name, index_col(object_name(i.id), i.indid, 5) column_name, 5 column_id, i.name as con_name 
    from sysindexes i, sysobjects o where object_name(i.id) = 'tbl_pk_mult' and user_name(o.uid) = 'dbo'  and  status & 2048 = 2048 and i.id = o.id and index_col(object_name(i.id), i.indid, 5) is not null         union         
select user_name(o.uid) user_name, object_name(i.id) table_name, index_col(object_name(i.id), i.indid, 6) column_name, 6 column_id, i.name as con_name 
    from sysindexes i, sysobjects o where object_name(i.id) = 'tbl_pk_mult' and user_name(o.uid) = 'dbo'  and  status & 2048 = 2048 and i.id = o.id and index_col(object_name(i.id), i.indid, 6) is not null         union         
select user_name(o.uid) user_name, object_name(i.id) table_name, index_col(object_name(i.id), i.indid, 7) column_name, 7 column_id, i.name as con_name 
    from sysindexes i, sysobjects o where object_name(i.id) = 'tbl_pk_mult' and user_name(o.uid) = 'dbo'  and  status & 2048 = 2048 and i.id = o.id and index_col(object_name(i.id), i.indid, 7) is not null         union         
select user_name(o.uid) user_name, object_name(i.id) table_name, index_col(object_name(i.id), i.indid, 8) column_name, 8 column_id, i.name as con_name 
    from sysindexes i, sysobjects o where object_name(i.id) = 'tbl_pk_mult' and user_name(o.uid) = 'dbo'  and  status & 2048 = 2048 and i.id = o.id and index_col(object_name(i.id), i.indid, 8) is not null         union         
select user_name(o.uid) user_name, object_name(i.id) table_name, index_col(object_name(i.id), i.indid, 9) column_name, 9 column_id, i.name as con_name 
    from sysindexes i, sysobjects o where object_name(i.id) = 'tbl_pk_mult' and user_name(o.uid) = 'dbo'  and  status & 2048 = 2048 and i.id = o.id and index_col(object_name(i.id), i.indid, 9) is not null         union         
select user_name(o.uid) user_name, object_name(i.id) table_name, index_col(object_name(i.id), i.indid, 10) column_name, 10 column_id, i.name as con_name 
    from sysindexes i, sysobjects o where object_name(i.id) = 'tbl_pk_mult' and user_name(o.uid) = 'dbo'  and  status & 2048 = 2048 and i.id = o.id and index_col(object_name(i.id), i.indid, 10) is not null         union         
select user_name(o.uid) user_name, object_name(i.id) table_name, index_col(object_name(i.id), i.indid, 11) column_name, 11 column_id, i.name as con_name 
    from sysindexes i, sysobjects o where object_name(i.id) = 'tbl_pk_mult' and user_name(o.uid) = 'dbo'  and  status & 2048 = 2048 and i.id = o.id and index_col(object_name(i.id), i.indid, 11) is not null         union         
select user_name(o.uid) user_name, object_name(i.id) table_name, index_col(object_name(i.id), i.indid, 12) column_name, 12 column_id, i.name as con_name 
    from sysindexes i, sysobjects o where object_name(i.id) = 'tbl_pk_mult' and user_name(o.uid) = 'dbo'  and  status & 2048 = 2048 and i.id = o.id and index_col(object_name(i.id), i.indid, 12) is not null         union         
select user_name(o.uid) user_name, object_name(i.id) table_name, index_col(object_name(i.id), i.indid, 13) column_name, 13 column_id, i.name as con_name 
    from sysindexes i, sysobjects o where object_name(i.id) = 'tbl_pk_mult' and user_name(o.uid) = 'dbo'  and  status & 2048 = 2048 and i.id = o.id and index_col(object_name(i.id), i.indid, 13) is not null         union         
select user_name(o.uid) user_name, object_name(i.id) table_name, index_col(object_name(i.id), i.indid, 14) column_name, 14 column_id, i.name as con_name 
    from sysindexes i, sysobjects o where object_name(i.id) = 'tbl_pk_mult' and user_name(o.uid) = 'dbo'  and  status & 2048 = 2048 and i.id = o.id and index_col(object_name(i.id), i.indid, 14) is not null         union         
select user_name(o.uid) user_name, object_name(i.id) table_name, index_col(object_name(i.id), i.indid, 15) column_name, 15 column_id, i.name as con_name 
    from sysindexes i, sysobjects o where object_name(i.id) = 'tbl_pk_mult' and user_name(o.uid) = 'dbo'  and  status & 2048 = 2048 and i.id = o.id and index_col(object_name(i.id), i.indid, 15) is not null         union         
select user_name(o.uid) user_name, object_name(i.id) table_name, index_col(object_name(i.id), i.indid, 16) column_name, 16 column_id, i.name as con_name 
    from sysindexes i, sysobjects o where object_name(i.id) = 'tbl_pk_mult' and user_name(o.uid) = 'dbo'  and  status & 2048 = 2048 and i.id = o.id and index_col(object_name(i.id), i.indid, 16) is not null
```

Answer (score -2):

I use Sybase ASA (not ASE) but you can try this query (it works on ASA).

For foreign key:

```
select f.* from sys.systable t 
join sys.SYSFOREIGNKEY f on t.table_id=f.primary_table_id
where t.table_name='xxx'
```

For primary key:

```
select c.* from sys.systable t
join sys.SYSCONSTRAINT c on t.object_id=c.table_object_id
where t.table_name='xxx' and c.constraint_type='P'
```